# Is there a way to change referenced value so that all references would be updated?

Tags: c#, reference

I want to declare local variables, add them to a List and then pass to a method that changes objects that are referenced by that list's elements.

However I need the original variables to reflect those changes, and they do not.

Is that even possible? Thanks a lot

```
class TestObject
{
    public int test;

    static TestObject test3 = new TestObject { test = 3 };
    static TestObject test4 = new TestObject { test = 4 };

    public static void Test()
    {
        TestObject test1 = new TestObject { test = 1 };
        TestObject test2 = new TestObject { test = 2 };

        List<TestObject> list = new List<TestObject>() { test1, test2 };

        Test2(list); // list[0] = 3 and list[1] = 4, but test1 still = 1 and test2 = 2
    }

    public static void Test2(List<TestObject> list)
    {
        list[0] = test3;
        list[1] = test4;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see how test1 and test2 are supposed to get updated. You are updating a list index that HAD test1 and test2. These indexes of list are replaced with test3 and test4.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or why.  The code effectively modifies the list, but there's nothing that re-assigns the `test1` or `test2` variables.  Did you mean to modify the objects referenced within the list, rather than modify the list itself?

Comment: But what if I need them to be updated? Is that possible somehow?

Comment: @Nidere: Modifying objects and modifying references to objects are two very different things.  This sounds like a classic example of an XY Problem.  Basically, you *don't* need those original variables to be updated in this case.  But something has led you to think that you do.  That something is the actual problem you're trying to solve.  But we don't know what that problem is, because you're currently focused only on what you thought the solution would be, which is incorrect.

Comment: Dave, thanks, I understand my mistake, but I still dont' see how I can update test1 and test2 values in Test2()

Comment: @Nidere: Well, you could do something like: `list[0].test = test3.test;`  This would modify the object to which `list[0]` points, which is the same object to which `test1` points.  Whether or not that solves your underlying problem is impossible to determine with the information/example provided.

Comment: If you want to update test1 and test2 inside Test2 then you'll need to make them global variables as well. Then set test1 = test3 and test2=test4 along with list[0] and list[1]. OR pass test1 and test2 as reference to the method Test2 and update them

Comment: The only problem there can be really more than test1, test2 ... testN, like dozens of variables - and they are local. So I need a convenient way to pass them all not like Test2(ref test1, ref test2, ref test3 ... ref testN), something like a collection of references?

Comment: Of course you can (and you don't need to make them global). You just have to modify the object that the list contains - like @David says. Your code doesn't modify the object in the list, it replaces it with a different object.

Comment: @iakobski how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people pointed out in the comments to the question, you probably don't need to reassign references if they are changed in the list - there may be a better solution for your problem. But if you do know that this is the way to go - that you need to fully replace the objects in the list and have those changes reflected elsewhere, then you can use a simple proxy and pass a list of proxies instead of a list of your objects.

```
public class Proxy<T>
{
    public Proxy(T obj)
    {
        this.Reference = obj;
    }

    public T Reference { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can create a list of proxies:

```
var test1 = new Proxy<TestObject>(new TestObject { test = 1 });
var test2 = new Proxy<TestObject>(new TestObject { test = 2 });

var list = new List<Proxy<TestObject>>() { test1, test2 };
```

And later you can reassign the values as you wish:

```
public static void Test2(List<Proxy<TestObject>> list)
{
    list[0].Reference = test3;
    list[1].Reference = test4;
}
```

Now after the method has returned, `test1` and `test2` will (indirectly) reference the new objects.

Having said that, I'd say that I think it's cumbersome and hacky - I'd rather change the actual objects than references to them (the proxies do just that).

Comment: Вот всегда поражала разница между дилетантским подходом и образом мышления опытного человека. Ни за что бы не додумался, хотя вроде элементарно. Спасибо! Мне правда это было нужно - просто описывать юз-кейс здесь было бы длинно и неудобно